# I want to convert variable from percentage to absolute

Tags: r

I want to convert percentage values into absolute, without mutate, in a long list of variables.

```
key b  c d 
25 2.2 6.1 4.4
34 9.2 3.1 5.4
23 3.2 9.1 6.4
45 5.2 6.2 7.4
```

here b, c, d variabes are in percentage. Lets assume key shows total no. And I want to convert b,c, d into absolute. so b = key*b/100, and similarly c and d.

I have use dplyr, but did not get success so far.

Many thanks, things are working:
[image: I donot want any change in ward_rev2, NO_HH, and ch_t_t]

Comment: Are you sure about the calculation? imho it should be `key*b/100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jogo if you want to calculate absolute value based on `key`, formula should be

```
df[-1] * df$key/100
```

which in `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(-1, ~ . * key/100)

#  key     b     c     d
#1  25 0.550 1.525 1.100
#2  34 3.128 1.054 1.836
#3  23 0.736 2.093 1.472
#4  45 2.340 2.790 3.330
```

Comment: Many thanks Ronak, working "df %>% mutate_at(-1, ~ . * key/100)". Just one minor point, if I donot want to touch one variable then how to exclude.

Comment: could you please suggest to exclude few column in this line "d_hl1 <- d_hl %>% mutate_at(-2, ~ . * No_HH/100)". I want to exclude first column "ward_rev2". Many thanks!

Comment: @S.Ahmad if you want to exclude first 2 columns you can add them like `d_hl1 <- d_hl %>% mutate_at(-(1:2), ~ . * No_HH/100)`

Answer (score 1):

**1) Base R** If `b`, `c`, `d` are percentages and `key` is the total then, as already noted in the comments, the absolute amount for `b` is `key * b / 100` (and not the formula shown in the question) so applying that to all columns at once we have the following.  `mutate` is not used and, in fact, no packages at all are used.

```
ix <- 1  # columns not to change.  Must include at least key column.
replace(DF, -ix, DF[-ix] * DF$key / 100)
```

giving:

```
  key     b     c     d
1  25 0.550 1.525 1.100
2  34 3.128 1.054 1.836
3  23 0.736 2.093 1.472
4  45 2.340 2.790 3.330
```

**2) %>% pipe** If you want to use dplyr then it could be written with `%>%` :

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% replace(-ix, .[-ix] * .$key / 100)
```

**3) %$% pipe** or with magrittr `%$%` :

```
library(magrittr)
DF %$% replace(., -ix, .[-ix] * key / 100)
```

### Note

`DF` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "key b  c d 
25 2.2 6.1 4.4
34 9.2 3.1 5.4
23 3.2 9.1 6.4
45 5.2 6.2 7.4"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Many thanks Grothendieck, it is working. Just a minor issue. lets assume I have another variable, I want to keep as it is. Then how to modify this formula.                                                    replace(DF, -1, DF[-1] * DF$key / 100)

Comment: Have modified code to parameterize by `ix` which is a vector of column numbers not to change, e..g.  `ix <- c(1, 3)` means do not change columns 1 and 3.  `ix` must include at least the key column.